# Do I need to list derived properties in Mongoose schema?

Tags: mongoose

Do I need to list derived properties in the Mongoose schema?  Is this a schema best practice?

I use a `.post('init')` hook to derive properties from saved values.  For example, I concatenate `fname` and `lname` to create `fullName` inside the post init hook middleware.

But this middleware doesn't work:

```
ContactSchema = new new mongoose.Schema({
  fname: String,
  lname: String 
});

ContactSchema.post('init',function(doc){
  doc.fullName= 'fname` + ' ' + 'lname';
});

// ... declare model

ContactModel.findOne({_id: req.params.contactId}).then(function(result){
  console.log(result);
  // {fname: "John",
  //  lname: "Smith"}
  //
  //  missing fullName!
});
```

unless I change the schema to also list `fullName`, then it works and the fullName property is set after `fineOne()` inside the middleware.

```
ContactSchema = new new mongoose.Schema({
  fname: String,
  lname: String,
  fullName: String,
});

ContactSchema.post('init',function(doc){
  doc.fullName= 'fname` + ' ' + 'lname';
});

// ... declare model

ContactModel.findOne({_id: req.params.contactId}).then(function(result){
  console.log(result);
  // {fname: "John",
  //  lname: "Smith",
  //  fullName: "John Smith"}
  //
  //  now fullName is populated and middleware works!
});
```

Should I be listing properties which will never be saved only so I can cause my middleware to work?  Is this a best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use [virtuals](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) instead.

For example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Create the schema.
var ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  fname: String,
  lname: String 
});

// Create a virtual property called `fullName`.
ContactSchema.virtual('fullName').get(function() {
  return this.fname + ' ' + this.lname;
});

// Create the model.
var Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema);

// Instantiate a contact.
var contact = new Contact({ fname : 'John', lname : 'Doe' });

// Print their full name.
console.log(contact.fullName);
```

Combined with a query, it's basically the same:

```
contact.save(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  Contact.findOne({}, function(err, contact) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(contact.fullName);
  });
});
```

The only caveat is that when you want to convert your document to a plain JS object (for instance, if you want to subsequently convert that to a JSON string), you have to tell Mongoose to also include virtuals:

```
// Log the entire document as JSON:
console.log('%j', contact.toObject({ virtuals : true }));
```

Comment: But I read somewhere we can't query the virtuals. Is that true?

Comment: My use case is with queries, and virtuals work if I use `toJSON` but virtuals do not seem to work after queries when using `toObject`.

Comment: @steampowered virtuals should work after queries too, see my edit. You still have to use the `{ virtuals : true }` though (both for `toObject()` and `toJSON()`).

Comment: @Vimal that's true, you can't query on virtuals because they aren't saved to the database.